# Issue in IE10 when website added to trusted sites error session expires

Tags: internet-explorer

Issue in IE10 when website added to trusted sites error session expires and website not open.
in Windows 7 profetional.

In logs Exception System.Web.HttpException:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got sol---------
by resetting internetoptions of ie -->advanced-->reset.
see below image
![enter image description here][1]
by resetting internetoptions-->advanced-->reset.